# Gremlin query to get all vertex and edges from root

Tags: gremlin, gremlin-server, azure-cosmosdb-gremlinapi

I want to output the properties for both edges and vertexes in a tree started on a given vertex. This is what I have so far:

```
g.V()
  .has('id', 'abc')
  .repeat(
    outE().as('edges').inV().as('vertexes').simplePath()
  )
  .emit()
  .select(
    'edges',
    'components'
  )
```

It seems to traverse and return the edges and vertexes a single branch, rather than getting for all branches.

I've not decided on the server yet so this needs to work in both Cosmos and Tinkertop for now

Comment: I'm not sure i'm clear about what you want your query to do because of the `select()` at the end. it is selecting two keys but i don't see where "edges" or "components" is being referenced. what format are you looking to get as an output? do you want an actual tree output? or a list of paths? something else?